# Resolver in angularjs routes

Tags: angularjs, routes

What is the purpose of route resolver in angularjs? How to check if the user is logged in or not using a $http Ajax request using the resolver before the route change?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official docs the route service is for

```
$route is used for deep-linking URLs to controllers and views (HTML partials). 
It watches $location.url() and tries to map the path to an existing route definition.
```

As for authentication, it depends what server routes you have available to notify you if a user has been authenticated already. Check out this question for more details [AngularJS: Use devise with multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995615/angularjs-use-devise-with-multiple-models)